Convert SVG to PNG using the command line with '-w' and '-h' values applied as a "box"
Here is an SVG image from Wikipedia:
(Downloadable version: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/CH-Hinweissignal-Wegweiser_f%C3%BCr_Hauptstrassen.svg)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 193.13333 47.626667"
   height="47.626667"
   width="193.13333"
   xml:space="preserve"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6" /><g
     transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,47.626667)"
     id="g10"><g
       transform="scale(0.1)"
       id="g12"><path
         id="path14"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="M 1.41797,1.41797 H 1135.27 l 311.8,177.07803 -311.8,177.266 H 1.41797 V 1.41797 v 0" /><path
         id="path16"
         style="fill:none;stroke:#231f20;stroke-width:2.83500004;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
         d="M 1.41797,1.41797 H 1135.27 l 311.8,177.07803 -311.8,177.266 H 1.41797 V 1.41797 v 0" /><path
         id="path18"
         style="fill:#1a67bb;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="M 22.6563,22.6953 H 1129.62 L 1291.15,178.535 1129.62,334.488 H 22.6563 V 22.6953" /><path
         id="path20"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 247.367,93.5742 h 117.106 v 25.2738 h -82.692 l 81.289,147.277 v 25.848 H 249.922 v -25.274 h 77.043 L 247.367,121.402 v -27.8278 0" /><path
         id="path22"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 406.738,266.699 h 25.02 v 29.844 h -25.02 v -29.844 0" /><path
         id="path24"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 453.359,266.699 h 25.02 v 29.844 h -25.02 v -29.844 0" /><path
         id="path26"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="M 470.137,93.5742 H 498 v 0 c -0.289,4.2461 -0.578,8.7888 -0.867,13.6448 -0.285,4.539 -0.285,9.363 -0.285,14.183 v 0 117.973 h -29.559 v -85.535 0 c 0,-11.379 -2.266,-20.485 -6.512,-27.289 -4.289,-6.844 -11.379,-10.262 -20.773,-10.262 -7.668,0 -13.07,2.559 -16.777,7.672 -3.672,5.144 -5.688,13.387 -5.688,24.73 v 0 90.684 h -29.555 v -97.488 0 c 0,-15.336 3.418,-27.582 10.223,-36.68 6.844,-9.0742 17.637,-13.6132 32.438,-13.6132 9.937,0 17.89,2.2343 23.867,7.0976 5.687,4.5316 10.226,10.2146 13.929,17.0236 v 0 h 0.579 l 1.117,-22.1408 v 0" /><path
         id="path28"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 539.867,93.5742 h 29.559 v 78.4418 c 0,7.382 0.863,13.648 2.551,19.047 1.695,5.402 4,9.683 6.808,13.07 2.84,3.129 6.266,5.687 9.969,7.414 3.672,1.402 7.344,2.266 11.629,2.266 1.691,0 3.383,0 4.824,-0.29 1.406,-0.285 3.133,-0.574 4.535,-0.863 v 0 28.442 0 c -0.578,0 -1.113,0 -1.402,0.289 -0.289,0 -0.863,0 -1.442,0 -5.398,0 -10.222,-0.575 -14.472,-2.016 -4.246,-1.406 -7.664,-3.383 -10.801,-5.941 -3.094,-2.555 -5.937,-5.403 -8.242,-8.532 -2.27,-3.129 -4.246,-6.554 -5.653,-10.257 v 0 h -0.578 v 0 c 0,1.152 0,2.839 0,5.144 -0.285,2.27 -0.285,4.824 -0.574,7.383 -0.289,2.555 -0.289,4.82 -0.289,7.09 C 566,236.527 566,238.258 566,239.375 v 0 h -27.285 v 0 c 0.289,-4.246 0.578,-8.785 0.867,-13.355 0.285,-4.825 0.285,-9.649 0.285,-14.473 v 0 -117.9728 0" /><path
         id="path30"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 632.422,93.5742 h 29.555 V 239.375 h -29.555 v -145.8008 0" /><path
         id="path32"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 631.559,268.676 h 31.285 v 31.539 h -31.285 v -31.539 0" /><path
         id="path34"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 794.707,97.5391 -1.687,25.0159 v 0 c -3.137,-1.981 -7.415,-3.707 -12.239,-5.114 -4.824,-1.433 -9.941,-2.265 -14.793,-2.265 -12.785,0 -22.433,4.531 -29.269,13.64 -7.098,9.075 -10.516,21.317 -10.516,36.653 0,17.926 3.418,30.996 10.223,39.527 6.847,8.527 16.484,12.777 29.015,12.777 5.399,0 10.223,-0.539 14.473,-1.976 4.285,-1.406 7.957,-2.848 11.668,-4.824 v 0 l 1.438,24.73 v 0 c -3.711,1.402 -7.989,2.844 -13.391,3.961 -5.399,1.152 -10.801,1.727 -16.199,1.727 -11.094,0 -21.028,-1.727 -29.563,-5.399 -8.531,-3.711 -15.621,-9.105 -21.308,-15.66 -5.688,-6.809 -9.969,-14.762 -12.778,-24.156 -2.847,-9.36 -4.289,-19.336 -4.289,-30.418 0,-10.227 1.442,-19.914 4,-28.985 2.555,-9.105 6.801,-17.066 12.203,-23.621 5.399,-6.511 12.243,-11.914 20.778,-15.6129 8.242,-3.9649 18.172,-5.9453 29.55,-5.9453 6.27,0 12.207,0.5742 18.184,1.7265 5.977,1.3672 10.801,2.8125 14.5,4.2188 v 0" /><path
         id="path36"
         style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
         d="m 822.824,93.5742 h 29.559 v 86.4028 c 0,11.375 2.265,20.484 7.129,26.996 4.531,6.55 11.379,9.687 20.734,9.687 7.664,0 13.067,-2.558 16.777,-7.672 3.418,-5.144 5.118,-13.386 5.118,-24.73 v 0 -90.6838 h 29.55 v 97.4888 0 c 0,15.332 -3.378,27.574 -10.226,36.679 -6.809,9.074 -17.598,13.649 -32.402,13.649 -9.676,0 -17.344,-2.27 -22.743,-6.551 -5.695,-4.539 -10.226,-9.363 -13.359,-14.797 v 0 h -0.578 v 86.723 h -29.559 v -213.1918 0" /></g></g></svg>

The following commands successfully converts it to 2000×493 and 406×100 pixel PNGs respectively:

inkscape -w 2000 input.svg -o output.png
inkscape -h 100 input.svg -o output.png

But if I specify both width and height (-w 2000 -h 100), both the values are used forcefully, and so the resulting image is distorted (2000×100 px).
Is it possible to specify them in such a way that they are applied as a "box" instead, that is,

inkscape -w 2000 -h 100 input.svg -o output.png should results in 2000×493 px image
inkscape -w 100 -h 2000 input.svg -o output.png should results in 100×25 px image


Are you sure you want 2000×493 instead of 406x100 in your first example? If yes, you could just omit the -h option.

As of 2024, Inkscape has no option to maintain the original aspect ratio (according to this issue).
Instead, use
rsvg-convert --width=2000 --height=100 --keep-aspect-ratio input.svg -o output.png

The output will be no wider than 2000px, no higher than 100px and will not be "streched" or "squished".

Thanks, Devon. Just in case, maybe you know why it isn't possible to convert the same image to JPEG? Whereas inkscape -w 2000 input.svg -o output.png works fine, replacing output.png with output.jpg gives errors.

You would need to append --format=jpg but that's currently not supported. You could do magick output.png output.jpg to convert the PNG to JPG (but note that JPG does not support transparency).

Do you have a link to the corresponding GitLab issue?

It seems rsvg-convert is not planning to add JPG support (which makes sense as PNG is superior for clip art).
